# Visual Studio installer project - adding another step to the uninstaller

Tags: visual-studio

I have a Visual Studio setup project where I need to add another step to the uninstaller for displaying some important info to the user. This needs to be done before the anything gets removed.

From within VS itself, it only seems possible to add new dialogs to the installation process.

How do I go about adding new dialogs to the uninstaller ?

Thanks!

Comment: Visual Studio deployment projects don't make all of the MSI functionality available.  I'm not sure how to do this, or if it's possible, with a VS project.  You can use Wix to do more complex things with Windows installers and uninstallers.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a project we have taken over which already uses the Visual Studio installer. My superiors are reluctant to invest the time and money required to switch to Wix.

Answer (score 0):

Cheat by adding a topic to the Help menu- Help/Before Uninstalling